# Lock and change cell contents depending on Option Button choice

Tags: vba, radio-button

I'm trying to lock certain cells, remove any values and change the cell colour based on a users option button selection but cannot get this to work.

For the 2 option buttons, I have the below code but am getting a 400 error - please can someone let me know what I'm missing?

```
 Sub Check_Method_Standard()

    ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 1").Value = 1
        With Me.Range("F18")
             .Locked = False
             .Interior.Color = 2747637
        End With
        With Me.Range("F19:F21")
             .Locked = True
             .Value = Null
             .Interior.Color = 16
        End With
    
    ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 1").Value = -4146
            With Me.Range("F19:F21")
             .Locked = False
             .Interior.Color = 2747637
        End With
        With Me.Range("F18")
             .Locked = True
             .Value = Null
             .Interior.Color = 16
        End With
End Sub

Sub Check_Method_Dual()

    ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 2").Value = 1
            With Me.Range("F19:F21")
             .Locked = False
             .Interior.Color = 2747637
        End With
        With Me.Range("F18")
             .Locked = True
             .Value = Null
             .Interior.Color = 16
        End With
    
    ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 2").Value = -4146
        With Me.Range("F18")
             .Locked = False
             .Interior.Color = 2747637
        End With
        With Me.Range("F19:F21")
             .Locked = True
             .Value = Null
             .Interior.Color = 16
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this on a worksheet or a Form?  Change 'ME' to 'ActiveSheet'... that will get you past your first hurdle, but you also need to declare your controls... e.g. not `ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 1").Value = 1`  That will not work.  You will need to Dim and Set the OptionButton first...

Comment: Thanks @GoodJuJu - this is a worksheet. I've changed ME to Active Sheet and added the following ....    Dim Inputs As String.....    Dim OptionButton1 As OptionButton....and am getting an error saying 'object doesn't support this property or method' what should I actually be putting as the dim/option button settings? Thank you.

Comment: Put your code back to how it was originally, but change `Me.` to `ActiveSheet.` and leave `ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 1").Value = 1` it may work as it's a WorkSheet not a form.

Comment: I've done as you said and am back to getting a 400 error - I'm puzzled?

Comment: It's working fine on my machine... have you right-clicked the OptionButton and assigned the macro to the button??

Comment: Yes, just double checked :) I don't understand what is wrong? I've tried changing values to xlOn/xlOff too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234820/discussion-between-goodjuju-and-nene).